# Jasmine avoid beforeEach for certain tests

Tags: jasmine

Is there a way to NOT execute beforeEach function only for certain tests ('it' blocks). Lets say I have 10 it blocks, I do not want beforeEach to be executed for two of the blocks. Is it possible?

Comment: Are you sure you want to prevent `beforeEach()` for certain tests and not just run setup code only once for all tests (related to your comment to Michaels answer)?

Answer (score 21):

You can group specs which you want to run with beforeEach into a separate `describe`:

```js
it('should 1...', function () {});
it('should 2...', function () {});

describe('group', function () {

    beforeEach(function () {
        // ...
    });

    it('should 3...', function () {});
    it('should 4...', function () {});

    // ...
});
```

Comment: Nice solution ! Thanks. But, my situation is slightly different. I need the 'should 3' and 'should 4' are part of a functional group. so I need something to happen before 'should 3', but not 'should 4'. In essence, I need something like a beforeDescribe. Possible?

Comment: So, my initial solution serves much better in this case. What do you think @Michael?

Comment: Do you mean that you want some code to be executed once before all specs inside `describe`? In this case [`beforeAll`](http://jasmine.github.io/2.1/introduction.html#section-Setup_and_Teardown) could help.

Comment: Yup. That sounds like a perfect solution.

Comment: @Aneesh, that (wanting `beforeAll()`) is contradictory to your question: "Lets say I have 10 it blocks, I do not want beforeEach to be executed for two of the blocks. Is it possible?"

Comment: Just to add more about this answer, which should be accepted, you can read the documentation in https://jasmine.github.io/2.1/introduction.html#section-Nesting_%3Ccode%3Edescribe%3C/code%3E_Blocks

Answer (score 3):

I currently managed this with a work around as follows:

```js
var executeBeforeEach = true;
function beforeEach() {
    if(!executeBeforeEach) return;
    //your before each code here.
}
describe('some test case 1', function(){
  it('Start', function(){
    //this is a dummy block to disable beforeeach for next test
  })
  it('The test that does not need beforeEach', function(){
    //this test does not need before each.
  })
  it('Start', function(){
    //this is a dummy block to enable beforeeach for next test
  })

})
```

But, I am wondering if there is a more elegant way!?!

Comment: The function should be named different than `beforeEach` and it should be added `beforeEach(setup);` (using `setup` as alternative name) before the `describe()`. Note that this will run unexpectedly when marking specs pending (disabling) or focusing specs using [`xit()`](https://jasmine.github.io/2.6/introduction.html#section-Pending_Specs) and [`fit()`](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/v2.6.4/src/core/Env.js#L481) (didn't know it's undocumented) or just deleting tests making the second test the first.