# Not able to test if nested function is called in Jasmine

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm learning to write test cases in jasmine ,I was trying to create  a test case to check if the functions defined within the function are called

My function that I'm trying to test is as follows,and the sData method is written in another component that is being extended by current component

```
public rPage() {
    this.sData();
    this.setupPage()
  }
```

the test case that i wrote is as below

```
   it('should check if  sData is called', () => {
    const sData = spyOn<any>(component, 'sData');
    component.rPage();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(sData).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

have created spy on rpage already in beforeeach as below

```
 beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BasicComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    spyOn(component, 'rPage');
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

still when i run the test ,the test case fails saying "Expected spy sData to have been called." ,where I'm going wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make sure that `sData` is called, you need to properly call `rPage`. By having `spyOn(component, 'rPage');` in your `beforeEach` , you are effectively telling all your tests to never run `rPage` for real, and to just mock it. So therefore it is never called for real, an `sData` really will never be called.

In order for you to check `rPage` properly, you need to not use a spy in the test that tests it, or add `.and.callThrough()` to the spy to the function is actually called

Comment: and how to make the spyon not being used for particular test?

Comment: you can remove it from your `beforeEach` and include it only in the tests you need. If you need it for multiple, you can use an inner `describe`.  Feel free to see this link for more information
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31182170/jasmine-avoid-beforeeach-for-certain-tests

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the function then defining the spy, this is what is causing the problem. You need to define the spy then call the function.

Try below

```typescript
  it('should check if sData is called', () => {
    const toggleSpy = spyOn<any>(component, 'sData');
    component.rPage();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(toggleSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Comment: it still fails to pass the test

Comment: is it something to related to the rPage being already mocked using spy @owen

Comment: The error says Expected spy **sData** to have been called. Can you share the code where you have defined a spy called **sData** /  **sDataSpy**

Comment: have updated it in the question,in the test case section @owen